# Delete keys from an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have an array of objects as shown below

```
[{
    '0': 'RECORD_KEY',
    '1': 'FIRST_TOUCH_DATE_TIME',
    '2': 'ISA_SENDER_ID'
  },
  {
    '0': '00208851228_1',
    '1': '2020-02-19 13:08:20.0',
    '2': 'CCA'
  }, {
    '0': ''
  }
]
```

I want to remove the key and the last object which is null.

So the result would be -

```
[{
    '0': 'RECORD_KEY',
    '1': 'FIRST_TOUCH_DATE_TIME',
    '2': 'ISA_SENDER_ID'
  },
  {
    '0': '00208851228_1',
    '1': '2020-02-19 13:08:20.0',
    '2': 'CCA'
  }
]
```

So each object would represent a row of data.
How can I possibly do this in node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Your desird outcome is not valid JS. What you need is a nested array(array of arrays):

```
const arr =[
  {
    '0': 'RECORD_KEY',
    '1': 'FIRST_TOUCH_DATE_TIME',
    '2': 'ISA_SENDER_ID'
  },
  {
    '0': '00208851228_1',
    '1': '2020-02-19 13:08:20.0',
    '2': 'CCA'
  },
  { '0': '' }
]

const mainArr = []

for(let item of arr){ 
  const subArr = []
  for(let prop in item){
    if(!item[prop]){
      continue;
    }
    subArr.push(item[prop])
  }
  if(subArr.length){
    mainArr.push(subArr)
  }
}
```

One note: Please next time provide a formatted code snippet